# Is it possible to list/access files stored after ios app update?

Tags: ios, swift, avasset

I store videos using AVAsset library. It's all working fine and I can watch videos offline.

But when the app gets updated, video stop playing.

The file was, let's say, downloaded to this location:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5D5DE2DB-4518-453D-AD27-5E32E5665FAF/Library/.../2921436_AE26A440BC211429.movpkg
```

But if I do `FileManage.fileExists` after app update, it says file doesn't exist.

I tried listing using this code to list all files:

```
extension FileManager {
    func urls(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, skipsHiddenFiles: Bool = true ) -> [URL]? {
        let documentsURL = urls(for: directory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURLs = try? contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: skipsHiddenFiles ? .skipsHiddenFiles : [] )
        return fileURLs
    }
}
```

It lists all files but the uuid of the file path is different than that of older stored file and it doesn't list the older file.

The question is is it possible to access the old downloaded file?

Comment: You are storing that file location somewhere then?

Comment: yes in coreData magical record

Comment: That number changes every update.  You cannot store it.

Comment: ya i got it, but unfortunately, i have users who already downloaded, will it be possible to access that file, I can see the file in system settings.

Comment: The files get migrated over during update and you can get that folder name from one of the standard `NSDocumentDirectory`'s can't you.  Just stop storing it.

Comment: you are storing full file path, so when app update, if you try to access your document directory path maybe changed, so you have to store the only filename and then each time append that file name by taking fresh document directory path and access that file.

Comment: yes thanks for reply. anyway just for record, in the contentsOfDirectory i can see the files too :)